# SQL Selección de 2 resultado o 1ro

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo un dilema el cual plasmo en este query de test:

```
   IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#T0') IS NOT NULL BEGIN   DROP TABLE #T0 END

CREATE TABLE #T0(
    [#] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [Caso] INT,
    [Dato] VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #T0 ([Caso],[Dato])
VALUES (1001,'uno'),(1001,'dos'),(1001,'tres'),(1002,'cuatro'),(1003,'cinco'),(1003,'seis'),(1003,'siete'),(1003,'ocho'),(1004,'nueve');


SELECT [Caso],[Dato],
       [Identificador] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caso] ORDER BY [Caso],[#] DESC) 
FROM #T0
```

Se obtiene el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que busco realizar es **obtener el resultado numero 2** de `[Identificador]` (de ley si o si), pero, si el `[Identificador]`  no tiene mas de 2 resultados (como el `[caso]` 1002 y 1004) **me consulte también el `[Identificador]` = 1**

Necesito ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ir tomando filas mediante el uso de CTEs en cascada.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [Caso],[Dato],
           [Identificador] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caso] ORDER BY [Caso],[#] DESC) 
    FROM #T0
),
CTE2 AS(
    SELECT Caso,
            Dato,
            Identificador,
            Identificador2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Caso] ORDER BY Identificador DESC) 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Identificador <= 2
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE2
WHERE Identificador2 = 1;
```

Comment: Lo haz vuelto a hacer Luis!! Gracias, tenia la idea del CTE pero no tenia la forma de implementarlo, con esto me queda muy claro.